# Implementing probability over time

Tags: python-3.x, probability

I have a set of 100 diseased people. According to data, the probability of them getting themselves reported/tested is 0.03. Let us assume that the count of the diseased remains a constant over 10 days. How do I implement the logic so that at the end of 10 days, 3-4 diseased people get reported? Assuming that the resolution of time chosen is 1-day. A small example of the current implementation is given below:

```
import numpy as np    
Population = 1000 # Total Population
# Store Infection Status
Infection_status = np.zeros(Population)
# Total Infections
Infection_status[:100] = 1
# Store Test Status
Test_status = np.zeros(Population)
for t in range(10):
   # generate N random numbers
   temp = np.random.uniform(0,1,Population)
   # Choose 1 in 30
   Test_status[(temp<0.03) & (Infection_status==1)] = 1
```

Comment: Without showing any approach you've tried so far, this is too broad to be answered – we're really not aware of what you *don't* understand, and we can't give you an introduction to both Python and Bernoulli-distributed random variables in the same answer.

Comment: @OP: Each day (`for _ in range(10)`), roll a random number between 0 and 1, check it against 0.03, do  this for each person (`for _ in range(100)`) and update the number of reports.

Comment: @MarcusMüller@Guimote please find the post updated with a snippet of the sample code. However, this implementation does not give the expected outcome.

Comment: @user3856486 and, what does it give instead?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Nearly 30 cases get reported/tested. And if I ran it for longer say 100 days, the count increases to 95-98.

Comment: that sounds about right?

Comment: Only 1 in every 30 cases will get reported, which should mean that only 3-4 of the 100 should get identified, isn't it?

Comment: no, that doesn't mean it; it means that only for a *single* day, but your `Test_status` persists over days. On the first day, you catch, say, 2 people, on the second day 4, on the third 3, but one of them was already caught on the first day. So you've now got 8 detected infections. Over time, your detection rate approaches 100%; how's that surprising?

Comment: nothing really to discuss, sorry.